# Connect Views and Models / Ruby-RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner in RoR. I have to develop a poll-generator so I created a three models app 'Formulaire' 'Question' and 'Reponse' with a 'rails generate scaffold' command. I'm not able to create my forms to generate my poll in the same view, i thought i coulde make a render of my questions/_form in my formulaire/_form but it doesn't work. I tried to make a form_for (question) in my form_for(@formulaire) in my view formulaires/_form

So how can i connect my three models and create my three entities in a same view?

Thank you

Comment: Please elaborate on _"it doesn't work"_. What did you try? What problem do you have? Was there an error message? Please show your code.

Comment: The problem is that i have to create Forms with Questions and Answers. I'm able to create Forms in my DB and Questions but i don't know how to connect each Form to several questions. For example i connected Users to Forms in my Formulaire controller with "@formulaire = current_user.formulaires.new" in my formulaires controller in my new method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby on Rails, the class-variables available to the view (`@something`), are set in the controllers action. So say that you have a UsersController, that has an `index` action. This would often define `@users = User.all`.

In the view, `app/views/users/index.html.erb`, you'd then be able to manage `@users`, or show these in a table or whatever.

What your question sounds like is that the scaffold has created a controller for each, but you'd like to manage them in the same view? Here you'll have to edit the Controller, to find these models as well, by initializing the model. `@question = Question.new` and `form_for(@question)`.

I'd recommend that you read http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html chapter 5 and 6, to get a basic understanding of the models, forms, and controllers.

EDIT:

Based on your answer below, I believe you should use `.questions.build` and not .new. As `.questions` will return an `ActiveRecord::Collection` as far as I remember, and you'll call `new` on this. The appropriate for building a new record, through a has_many-relationship, is to `.build` it. See following link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: Thank you for yout help, it helped me but i didn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could do something like create a master model called Formulaire, then a question model, and an answer model, and a comment model ...

A Formulaire would have many questions (has_many) and a question would have one or many answers (has_one or has_many).

Through Rails, controllers, views and models need to operate together. Meaning that if you want to add (or edit) a question, the simple thing to do is something like apps/views/questions/_edit.html.erb.

You could also do nested parameters.

```
def formulaire_params
    params.require(:formulaire).permit(
      : name,
      : subject, 
      : instructions,
      { questions: [:id, :description, :_destroy] },
      ...
    )
 end
```

In order to display a "formulaire", through the mas_many and has_one relations you've added (as well as proper scoping and authorizations), you'd easily be able to do something like

```
<% @formulaire.questions.each do |question| %>
  <span class=""><%= question.description %></span>
  <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <span class=""><%= answer.owner.name %></span>
    <span class=""><%= answer.description %></span>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Michel for your answer. I did what you explained but i have an error : NoMethodError in Questions#new
in my app/views/questions/_form.html.erb class 

undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Can you post your controller for formulaires and questions?

Answer (score 0):

My 'formulaire controller'

```
def new
@formulaire = current_user.formulaires.new
end
```

My view formulaire/_form

```
  <%= form_for (@formulaire), html: {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

My question controller

```
def new
 @question = current_user.questions.new
end
```

My view questions/_form

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
```

I tried with 'form_for([@formulaire, @formulaire.questions.new]) do |f| %>
But i had a NoMethodError in Questions#new

Ty.

Comment: I updated my answer to fit the new information. That should work.